# Unknown column 'lat' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm tweaking a `wp_query` quite a lot with the `add_filter` function.

I'm getting this error from wordpress: `Unknown column 'lat' in 'field list'`

The final SQL output is like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.*, 
( 3959 * acos(
    cos( radians(52.486243) ) 
    * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
    * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-1.890401) ) 
    + sin( radians(52.486243) ) 
    * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
) ) 
AS distance , lat AS  latitude , lng AS longitude 
FROM wp_posts  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
INNER JOIN lat_lng_post ON wp_posts.ID = lat_lng_post.post_id 
WHERE 1=1  
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_start-date' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= '20140704')
AND (mt1.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_end-date' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '20140627') ) 
AND lat_lng_post.lat = lat 
AND lat_lng_post.lng = lng 
AND substr(wp_postmeta.meta_key, 1, 6) = substr(mt1.meta_key, 1, 6)  
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
HAVING distance <= 18 
ORDER BY distance ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

I thought the `AND lat_lng_post.lat = lat` and `AND lat_lng_post.lng = lng` lines would have sorted the unknown column issue?

Does anyone know what's wrong with the query?

[EDIT]

lat and lng are columns in the wordpress db in a custom table. The table was made using this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'lat_lng_post' (
'post_id' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,     
'lat' float NOT NULL,     
'lng' float NOT NULL   ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

[EDIT 2]

Just noticed that the under the error the SQL Query outputted is different the the SQL that is being shown with `var_dump($wp_query->request)`.

Below is the SQL that is showing below the error `Unknown column 'lat' in 'field list'.

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, 
( 3959 * acos( 
    cos( radians(52.486243) ) 
    * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
    * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-1.890401) ) 
    + sin( radians(52.486243) ) 
    * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
) ) AS distance , lat AS latitude , lng AS longitude 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'acf-field' 
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
AND wp_posts.post_name = 'field_535e6b9ffe3da' 
AND lat_lng_post.lat = lat 
AND lat_lng_post.lng = lng 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
HAVING distance <= 25 
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```

This is quite different to what I want to be querying for some reason.

I'm not sure if the issue may be with the `add filter` functions being added to the query breaking it?

Comment: in which table `lat` column is in ?

Comment: Where is `lat` or even `lng` defined?

Comment: Question edited to explain where lat and lng come from

Comment: Are you sure the error happens on this `SELECT` rather than on a different `INSERT` or `UPDATE`?

Comment: Just updated question, I noticed the query under the error was different to what was in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually not with the SQL or Database itself, but with the `add_filter` function being used to change the WordPress `wp_query` into the above code.

I need to `remove_filter()` after the query, which got rid of the error and left the SQL as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You indicate in the first edit that the lat column comes from lat_lng_post, but then you are trying to select it from wp_posts - it does not exist in that table, hence the unknown column error.

I can't see an obvious way to make the query work with the information you've given.

However, if there is another way to join the lat_lng_post to wp_posts on e.g. wp_posts.id matching lat_lng.post_id you could do it as follows, joining the tables then projecting the relevant fields from lat_lng:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, 
( 3959 * acos( 
    cos( radians(52.486243) ) 
    * cos( radians( lat_lng.lat ) ) 
    * cos( radians( lat_lng.lng ) - radians(-1.890401) ) 
    + sin( radians(52.486243) ) 
    * sin( radians( lat_lng.lat ) ) 
) ) AS distance , lat_lng.lat AS latitude , lat_lng.lng AS longitude 
FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN lat_lng 
ON (wp_posts.id = lat_lng.post_id)
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'acf-field' 
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
AND wp_posts.post_name = 'field_535e6b9ffe3da' 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
HAVING distance <= 25 
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Yes, `post_id` is in the `lat_lng_post` table which can be used to match the `ID` from `wp_posts`. However, I don't really understand how the query can be so different from what has been written out to what was ended up in the error report.